# WebMvcTest when Multiple TemplateResolver

Tags: spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf

I have added a second TemplateResolver because I would like to use also Thymeleaf to serve Template for Plain-Text Templates. When starting application it works fine, the Thymeleaf templates are being resolved.

But from now my @WebMvcTests are not working. I says, that:

```
Error resolving template [disclaimer/view], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

The TemplateResolver are configures like:

```
@Configuration
public class SitemapViewResolverConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTextTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/sitemap/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".txt");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(TRUE);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class PageViewResolverConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafHtmlTemplateResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/view/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(TRUE);
        return templateResolver;
     }
 }
```

My template structure is as follows:
[image]

The test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DisclaimerController.class)
public class DisclaimerControllerTest {
    @Autowired MockMvc            mvc;

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {

        mvc.perform(get("/disclaimer")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("disclaimer/view"))
            ;

}
```

}

Error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [disclaimer/view], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the problem. As I use @WebMvcTest it didn't load my TemplateResolver. As before I relied on Spring Boot automatic resolver, I am using now two selfmade resolver. But they are not picked up by the test, that's why MockMvc could not resolve it.

I fixed it by adding Configuration as Import:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest({PageViewResolverConfiguration.class, DisclaimerController.class})
public class DisclaimerControllerTest {
    ...
}
```